# How to reflect modified abstract syntax tree in JDT back to original java source file.?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, ajdt

Kindly refer "write it down" section of article
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-javaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html

I am parsing a java source code file which has method with contracts written using cofoja. Now when I create abstract syntax tree (ast) of the input file, and modify it. It can show me that Document document, object being modified. But when I try to reflect this document back to the original source file, the following declaration throws an exception:

```
 // get the buffer manager  
 ITextFileBufferManager bufferManager = FileBuffers.getTextFileBufferManager();
```

The following exception gets thrown for `ITextFileBufferManager bufferManager` declaration in MyVisitor.java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ASTModifier.main(ASTModifier.java:205)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:340)
at org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.FileBuffers.<clinit>(FileBuffers.java:52)
... 1 more
```

Because of this, I am not able to change the original java file. One of the link I found  on net :  http://www.programcreek.com/2011/05/java-lang-illegalstateexception-workspace-  is-closed/#comment-1939

It says: In brief, this is caused by simply adding dependent jar files to regular java project.  To use JDT, you need to have the program running as a plug-in (or at least, an OSGi-     enabled application) rather than using it as a jar.

Since I am creating a simple java project, is that a problem for using FileBuffers class? Do I need to create plug in instead?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.  You can only use JDT API if you are running with a workspace that is opened (i.e., you have written an Eclipse plugin).

If you want to write a simple program that uses Eclipse API, you probably want to write an RCP application.  This allows you to use a sib0set of Eclipse plugins to create some functionality.

A good tutorial on RCP is here:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html

Comment: Hey..what if I create an eclipse plugin instead of RCP application? Whether will I be able to use JDT in eclipse plugin? and whether I will be able to display output on console window?

Comment: Yes.  You can create a plugin instead of an RCP app.  But, if you only create a plugin, then it will only be able to be run as part of an eclipse application (and so you would need a way to plug your plugin into Eclipse in order to invoke its functionality).  If you create an application yourself, you have full control over how your functionality is invoked.